# Calling Clojure from native code via JNI

Tags: clojure, java-native-interface

I am running some compiled C code am loading a JVM into the process and executing some Java code within it (via JNI). Is it possible to do the same thing, but instead call compiled Clojure code within the native process?

I have aot compiled a simple Clojure namespace and see the files below. If I were calling into, say, Java, I would load a single class file and search for a method and then invoke it via JNI, however I suspect the equivalent for Clojure is not going to be as easy.

```
calc$cplus.class
calc$fn__63.class
calc$loading__4958__auto__.class
calc__init.class
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a java class that calls your Clojure and call that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the last section of this [page](http://clojure.org/java_interop) on Java Clojure interop.

Basically, you don't need to manually load the classes generated by AOT. Since you have already the tools to call Java methods on hand, there is nothing different when you want to call Java methods that finally calls some Clojure functions.